# Cuckoo Error: TemplateDoesNotExist at /

Tags: django, python-2.7, sandbox, malware-detection

I installed last Cuckoo version on my physical machine Ubuntu 15.10 and I configured cuckoo following official guide.
I have problem with web gui:
**TemplateDoesNotExist at /**
and it tries to search *dashboard* template in 
*usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/dashboard/index.html* (with *File does not exist* error)
instead of to search it in *~/cuckoo/web/templates/dashboard/*

I tried to search a solution in cuckoo official support but it seems to be deserted.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have TEMPLATE_DIR and TEMPLATE_LOADERS in your settings.py file. I faced the same issues too. Once you do this, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in web/settings.py it works

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
from os.path import join
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
)
```